# How to attach an event in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I try to attach an event on a input element, then I put this code on `onload` of body element:

```
bornDate.attachEvent("onblur", validade(true));
```

But in onload, the function `validade` executes! I want the function executes only on `onblur` of `bornDate` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep validade from executing, you have to embed the function call inside a function. The function reference gets passed to attachEvent.

```
bornDate.attachEvent("onblur", function () {
    validade(true);
});
```